# Exact query on embedded mongodb document does not work

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

According to the mongodb documention on querying for embedded documents, it is possible to do an exact query by specifying all the fields of the document in the same order as they are stored.

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-embedded-documents

```
db.bios.find(
    {
      name: {
              first: "Yukihiro",
              last: "Matsumoto"
            }
    }
)
```

This does not appear to work for me. Even if I retrieve the document using find_one and then copy-paste it, the search returns nothing.

```
In [57]: TestColl.find_one({'data.local_dt': {'$exists': True}})
Out[57]: 
{u'_id': ObjectId('570ddba7f6858f77be9fb8ac'),
 u'data': {u'local_dt': {u'hour': 22, u'month': 4, u'year': 2016}}}

In [58]: TestColl.find({'data.local_dt': {u'hour': 22, u'month': 4, u'year': 2016}}).count()
Out[58]: 0
```

Full set of steps to reproduce:

```
In [1]: from pymongo import MongoClient

In [2]: TestColl = MongoClient().Stage_database.TestColl

In [3]: TestColl.remove()
Out[3]: {u'n': 2, u'ok': 1}

In [4]: TestColl = MongoClient().Stage_database.TestColl

In [5]: doc = {'data': {'local_dt': {'year': 2016, 'month': 4, 'hour': 22}}}

In [6]: TestColl.insert(doc)
Out[6]: ObjectId('570ddfe7f6858f84169707fd')

In [7]: TestColl.find_one({'data.local_dt': {'$exists': True}})
Out[7]: 
{u'_id': ObjectId('570ddfe7f6858f84169707fd'),
 u'data': {u'local_dt': {u'hour': 22, u'month': 4, u'year': 2016}}}

In [8]: TestColl.find({'data.local_dt': {u'hour': 22, u'month': 4, u'year': 2016}}).count()
Out[8]: 0

In [9]: TestColl.find({'data.local_dt': {'hour': 22, 'month': 4, 'year': 2016}}).count()
Out[9]: 0
```

Comment: I think what you are missing here is that even though the python dict is showing the keys in a particular order ( by key name ) they are not actually stored that way in the database. if you looked in the `mongo` shell then I think this would be confirmed. Therefore the "correct" way to do this would be the "dot notation" path to each property, rather than expecting an **exact match**. It's quite reasonable and exactly why the "dot notation" form exists, so you can test values on "properties" and not just an "exact  object".

Comment: I agree that the dot notation works. My question was not "how do I search for embedded fields in a document?", but "why does the exact query not work?" If it doesn't work in any reasonable way, then why does the exact object query even exist?

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that retrieval order is what should be used for querying - but instead it should be insertion order. As you can see the order you used for insertion was `year`, `month`, `hour`.

Therefore, instead of

```
TestColl.find({'data.local_dt': {'hour': 22, 'month': 4, 'year': 2016}}).count()
```

Do

```
TestColl.find({'data.local_dt': {'year': 2016, 'month': 4, 'hour': 22}}).count()
```

As you said in the question and in the [MongoDB docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#:%7E:text=Equality%20matches%20on%20the%20whole%20embedded%20document%20require%20an%20exact%20match%20of%20the%20specified%20%3Cvalue%3E%20document%2C%20including%20the%20field%20order.%20For%20example%2C%20the%20following%20query%20does%20not%20match%20any%20documents%20in%20the%20inventory%20collection%3A) it states

> Equality matches on the whole embedded document require an exact match of the specified  document, including the field order.

---

### Generic MongoDB example

I have reproduced what you did in this [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8K4wkkOwVa1) and this is what you should've done [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HJ43539tuQN)

### pymongo example

The [MongoDB docs (Chosen language: python, in sidebar)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#query-on-embedded-nested-documents) state

> Subdocument key order matters in a few of these examples so we have
> to use bson.son.SON instead of a Python dict.
> from bson.son import SON

However, as of python3.7 and up `dict`s are insertion ordered and therefore using `bson.son.Son` is no longer required.

Example altered from [MongoDB docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#match-an-embedded-nested-document)

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
db = MongoClient().test_db
db.inventory.insert_one({"item": "journal", "size": { "h": 14, "w": 21, "uom": "cm" }})
# returns 1
db.inventory.count_documents( { "size": { "h": 14, "w": 21, "uom": "cm" } } )
# returns 0 since order doesn't match.
db.inventory.count_documents( { "size": { "w": 21, "h": 14, "uom": "cm" } } )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
TestColl.find({'data.local_dt': {'hour': 22, 'month': 4, 'year': 2016}}).count()
```

you should use *. notation*

```
TestColl.find({
    "data.local_dt.hour": 22,
    "data.local_dt.year": 2016,
    "data.local_dt.month": 4
})
.count()
```

Comment: I knew that worked. My goal is not to figure out how to query for subfields, but to understand why the exact query doesn't work. Think of it as an intellectual exercise!